# PyQt5 won't show Picture in lable

Tags: python, linux, windows, pyqt5

I'm trying to show a picture after being taken from camera in PyQt5. Well I wrote this code on Linux and it worked, but when I switched to Windows almost everything broke. So I fix some of the problems but I couldn't fix this one.
I am trying to show an Image in a label which is in a frame. When I pass the image's directory, directly to the QPixmap, it works fine but the image directory is dynamic and changing and I need that.
The function is like this:

'''

```
ave_directory = global_path + "temp_pics\\"
if not os.path.exists(save_directory):
    os.makedirs(save_directory)
pic_num = self.save_seq.pop()
save_directory += str(pic_num)
self.capture.capture(save_directory)
pic_show_dir = str(save_directory + ".jpg")
time.sleep(1)
# pic_show = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\***\\***\\temp_pics\\logo.png")
pic_show = QtGui.QPixmap(pic_show_dir)

if pic_num == "1":
    self.lbl_pic1.setPixmap(pic_show)
elif pic_num == "2":
    self.lbl_pic2.setPixmap(pic_show)
elif pic_num == "3":
    self.lbl_pic3.setPixmap(pic_show)
elif pic_num == "4":
    self.lbl_pic4.setPixmap(pic_show)
elif pic_num == "5":
    self.lbl_pic5.setPixmap(pic_show)
elif pic_num == "6":
    self.lbl_pic6.setPixmap(pic_show)
```

'''

When I write `pic_show = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\***\\***\\temp_pics\\logo.png")` it works fine but the dynamic one, won't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you thought of comparing the hardcoded and dynamic paths, even by just printing them on two different lines?

Comment: Yes. I tried comparing both. One worked and one didn't. I put Warning Message after taking picture and it made the dynamic part work! I tried putting some delay into code like time.sleep() and it didn't. So the problem is solved by adding Warning Message but don't know why.

Comment: sorry but your comment is very confusing. I suggest you to add a simple print statement for both strings, and show us the result by editing your post.

Answer (score -1):

I put Warning Message after taking picture and it made the dynamic part work! I tried putting some delay into code like time.sleep() and it didn't. So the problem is solved by adding Warning Message but don't know why!

Comment: This doesn't seem a very valid answer, as the solution seems more like an unrelated workaround, which usually indicates an unreliable and *wrong* solution. Please use the answer field only when you have complete and reliable answers.